# ModPay Payment Gateway HowTo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, payment

**UPDATE:**  I've narrowed it down to the Ajax call.  I can use a normal form post submission, still using the same PHP code and it works.  The Ajax does not.  So if anyone familiar with Ajax has an idea... Or if you have a better idea of how to do a POST from code without user interaction...

**UPDATE 2:**
If I replace the GetPaymentSetup() function with the below code, it also works, using the PostTo.  It seems to be something with the redirection...

```
    public function GetPaymentSetup() {
        $script1 = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            function post_to_url() {
                var form = document.createElement('form');
                form.action = '" . self::PROXY_URL . "';
                form.method = 'POST';

                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.type = 'hidden';
                input.name = 'clientId';
                input.value = '" . self::CLIENTID . "';
                document.body.appendChild(input);
                form.appendChild(input);

                var input1 = document.createElement('input');
                input1.type = 'hidden';
                input1.name = 'clientCode';
                input1.value = '" . self::CLIENTCODE . "';
                document.body.appendChild(input1);
                form.appendChild(input1);

                var input2 = document.createElement('input');
                input2.type = 'hidden';
                input2.name = 'postTo';
                input2.value = '" . self::POSTTO_URL . "';
                document.body.appendChild(input2);
                form.appendChild(input2);

                var input3 = document.createElement('input');
                input3.type = 'hidden';
                input3.name = 'target';
                input3.value = 'GetPaymentSetup';
                document.body.appendChild(input3);
                form.appendChild(input3);

                form.submit();
            }
        </script>";
        $html2 = "<br><button id='hidformbtn' onclick=\"post_to_url()\">Click 3</button><br>";

        echo $script1;
        echo $html2;
}
```

I guess this will work. I need to automate it in some cases, but that's not a problem.  I'd just like to know why the jQuery/Ajax fails.

---

I have searched everywhere, but cannot find any questions related to this system.  So I need some guidance, and perhaps as a reference to anyone in the future using this.  I've been tasked to integrate with ModPay.com's payment system.  It's also known as TotalTransact.  For testing purposes, they have a simple enough page you can do a POST to and get back a response without any real data exchange.  I have written code that works with this, but when I add an option to "PostTo a different url", I don't get back a response.  First, here is how the option is described in their API documentation:

> If you supply a PostTo=URL argument, the results of the call to the
>   xxxxx  page will post its results to the url provided rather than
>   returning a web page with  the results.

I want to post the results to a different url for splitting out parsing more easily.  If I don't use this parameter, I get the results back ok from the page sending out the request.  If I use the parameter, I still get a successful POST, but nothing back.  Their developers are scratching their heads, so I am more inclined to think it is something with my code.

I have verified that they can post directly to my PostTo url.  So I know that's not the issue.  I have also added "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" headers to make sure they can post back ok to avoid cross-domain issues.

Here is the relevant code in PHP:

```
function post($url, $data) {
    $header = array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ;
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);  //This option returns some data to the screen
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, ''); //write cookies.  empty string to ignore.
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, ''); //read cookies
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOPROXY, 1); // causes POST to fail
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:"));
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
```

where

```
$data = http_build_query($_POST, '', '&');
```

and $_POST is coming from an AJAX call on another page (proxy to avoid browser CORS issues):

```
public function GetPaymentSetup($useButton) {
    $script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
    if($useButton == true) {
        $script .= "
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(\"button\").click(function() {
        ";
    }
    $script .= "
        var request = jQuery.ajax ({
            type:   'POST',
            url:    '" . self::PROXY_URL . "',
            crossDomain: true,
            data:       { \"clientId\"      : \"" . self::CLIENTID . "\",
                          \"clientCode\"    : \"" . self::CLIENTCODE . "\",
                          \"postTo\"        : \"" . self::POSTTO_URL . "\" 
                        }
            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        $('#dresponse').html(responseData);
                     },
            error:   function(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $('#dresponse').html('Error. POST failed.');
                     }
        });";
    if($useButton == true) {
        $script .= "
        });});";
    }
    $script .= " </script>";
    if($useButton == true)
        $html = "<button>click</button><div id='dresponse'></div>";
    else
        $html = "<div id='dresponse'></div>";
    echo $script;
    echo $html;
}
```

Can anyone explain why when I use this line:

```
                      \"postTo\"        : \"" . self::POSTTO_URL . "\"
```

the POSTTO_URL page never gets anything back.  But if I remove the line, I get a response back?  And again, with the POSTTO_URL, I don't get an error back in the original AJAX call either, so it acts as a successful POST.  I can verify this by changing the CLIENTID to something else, then I get a failure.

Is this something I'm doing, or something incorrect on their end? Does anyone have any experience integrating with them?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I should also mention that all the commented out curl options make no difference present or not, whether I use the PostTo or not.

Comment: What happens if you put the `postTo` url directly in there?

Comment: Nothing changes.  I assume you mean \"postTo\" : \"https://xxxx\", correct?

Comment: something like `postTo: 'xxxx'`

Comment: Nope.  I did add an update above, UPDATE 2, showing how it can work successfully if I don't use jQuery/Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one has had any insight on why the original Ajax/jQuery fails.  But I do have a working solution, so here it is below for anyone looking in the future for TotalTransact/ModPay integration:

Create a file: modPayProcessing.php:

```
<?php
class modPayProcessing {
    const CLIENTCODE = "xxxxxxx";
    const CLIENTID = "xxxxxx";
    const PROXY_URL = "https://....modPayProxy.php";
    const POSTTO_URL = "https://....modPayReceive.php";

    public function GetPaymentSetup($useButton=false, $usePostTo=false) {
        $script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            function post_to_url() {
                var form = document.createElement('form');
                form.action = '" . self::PROXY_URL . "';
                form.method = 'POST';

                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.type = 'hidden';
                input.name = 'clientId';
                input.value = '" . self::CLIENTID . "';
                document.body.appendChild(input);
                form.appendChild(input);

                var input1 = document.createElement('input');
                input1.type = 'hidden';
                input1.name = 'clientCode';
                input1.value = '" . self::CLIENTCODE . "';
                document.body.appendChild(input1);
                form.appendChild(input1);
        ";
        if($usePostTo === true) {
            $script .= "
                var input2 = document.createElement('input');
                input2.type = 'hidden';
                input2.name = 'postTo';
                input2.value = '" . self::POSTTO_URL . "';
                document.body.appendChild(input2);
                form.appendChild(input2);
            ";
        }
        $script .= "
                var input3 = document.createElement('input');
                input3.type = 'hidden';
                input3.name = 'target';
                input3.value = 'GetPaymentSetup';
                document.body.appendChild(input3);
                form.appendChild(input3);

                form.submit();
            }
        ";
        if($useButton == true) {
            $html = "<button id='hidformbtn' onclick=\"post_to_url()\">Submit</button>";
            $script .= "</script>";
        }
        else {
            $html = "";
            $script .= "
            if(window.onload) {
                var currOnload = window.onload;
                var newOnload = function() {
                    currOnload();
                    post_to_url();
                };
                window.lonload = newOnload;
            }
            else {
                window.onload = post_to_url();
            }
        </script>";
        }

        echo $script;
        echo $html;
    }

    public function PostPayment($useButton, $usePostTo=false) {
    // Same as the above function, but change the input.name/value to be for whatever you want to submit
    // Implementations of how to retrieve the data vary, so I am not listing it exactly here, but the basic format is the same.
    }
```

Create a file: modPayProxy.php:

```
//You can use Curl, or you can use php Streams.  Below is a function for each:
<?php
    function postCurl($url, $data) {
        $header = array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 3);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);  //This option returns some data to the screen
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $response;
    }

    function postStreams($url, $data) {
        $params = array(
            'http' => array(
                'method'=>'POST',
                'content'=>$data,
                'header'=>array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" . "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n"),
                'user_agent'=>"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"
            )
        );
        $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
        $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
        if(!$fp) {
            throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
        }
        $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
        fclose($fp);
        if($response === false) {
            throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
        }
        return $response;
    }

    if(array_key_exists('target', $_POST)) {
        if($_POST['target'] == 'GetPaymentSetup')
            $url = GETSETUP_URL;
        elseif($_POST['target'] == 'PostPayment')
            $url = POST_URL;
        else
            $url = "";

        unset($_POST['target']);
        $data = http_build_query($_POST, '', '&');

        echo(postStreams($url, $data)); //change to postCurl if you prefer
    }
    else {  // if POSTTO_URL is not used in the calling function.
        $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
        parse_str($postdata, $output);
        // Do whatever you want with $output now.
    }
```

Create a file, modPayReceive.php:

```
<?php
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    parse_str($postdata, $output);
    // Now do whatever you want with $output now.
```

To initiate a call, make sure you require modPayProcessing.php, then:

```
$cc = new modPayProcessing();
$cc->GetPaymentSetup(true, false);
```

If the second argument is false, it won't use the POSTTO_URL / modPayReceive.php file.
The first argument can be set to true to have this as a button on a form.  Or false to process directly (a better idea so you don't expose your clientID, etc.)